# How to remove noise from an image in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

How to remove noise from an image in opencv (see the input picture)? I want to achieve that in the output I will get white background and black text only.

[image]

Comment: You applied some processing steps to get to this image. Those steps are not good. Go back to your original image, and find a better way to binarize it.

Comment: as @CrisLuengo says, it's better to work with original image to get better results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming grayscale image, you can partially eliminate the noise like this:

```
# thresholding
thresh, thresh_img = cv.threshold(img, 128, 255, 0, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

# erode the image to *enlarge* black blobs
erode = cv.erode(thresh_img, cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3)))

# fill in the black blobs that are not surrounded by white:
_, filled, _, _ = cv.floodFill(erode, None, (0,0), 255)

# binary and with the threshold image to get rid of the thickness from erode
out = (filled==0) & (thresh_img==0)
# also
# out = cv.bitwise_and(filled, thresh_img)
```

The output is not clean (some dark blobs between the text lines, which can be further removed by thresholding the sizes of connected components), but this should be a good start:

[image]